# How to Convert List to ObservableCollection?

Tags: list, windows-phone-7, listbox

I am a java Developer,new to C# silverlight.
in this class I want to Convert the Products(List) to ObservableCollection.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Linq;

namespace WPListBoxImage
{
/**It seems not work,if I just change List<Product> to ObservableCollection<Product>
  public class Products : List<Product>
  {
    public Products()
    {
      BuildCollection();

    }

    private const string IMG_PATH = "../Images/";

    public ObservableCollection<Product> DataCollection { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Product> BuildCollection()
    {
      DataCollection = new ObservableCollection<Product>();

      DataCollection.Add(new Product("Haystack Code Generator for .NET", 799, IMG_PATH + "Haystack.jpg"));
      DataCollection.Add(new Product("Fundamentals of N-Tier eBook", Convert.ToDecimal(19.95), IMG_PATH + "FundNTier_100.jpg"));
      DataCollection.Add(new Product("Fundamentals of ASP.NET Security eBook", Convert.ToDecimal(19.95), IMG_PATH + "FundSecurity_100.jpg"));
      DataCollection.Add(new Product("Fundamentals of SQL Server eBook", Convert.ToDecimal(19.95), IMG_PATH + "FundSQL_100.jpg"));
      DataCollection.Add(new Product("Fundamentals of VB.NET eBook", Convert.ToDecimal(19.95), IMG_PATH + "FundVBNet_100.jpg"));
      DataCollection.Add(new Product("Fundamentals of .NET eBook", Convert.ToDecimal(19.95), IMG_PATH + "FundDotNet_100.jpg"));
      DataCollection.Add(new Product("Architecting ASP.NET eBook", Convert.ToDecimal(19.95), IMG_PATH + "ArchASPNET_100.jpg"));
      DataCollection.Add(new Product("PDSA .NET Productivity Framework", Convert.ToDecimal(2500), IMG_PATH + "framework.jpg"));

      return DataCollection;
    }
  }
}
```

what should I do to fix it? or need to create a new class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Products class shouldn't inherit anything.

```
public class Products
```

Accessing all the items in your collection is done through the DataCollection property of the Product class. For example,

```
Products myProducts = new Products();
ObservableCollection<Product> myData = myProducts.DataCollection;
```

It also depends on how you want to use Products.  You may be able to totally do away with this class and then do something like:

```
ObservableCollection<Product> Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
Products.Add(new Product("Haystack Code Generator for .NET", 799, IMG_PATH + "Haystack.jpg"));
// etc...
```

Comment: You're genius! Indeed,I've been confused for this question yestoday.but can't find solution until now.Do you mind go to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662479/remove-an-item-from-listbox-in-wp7),and Paste this answer for someone had some problem ,I'll mark the answer.

Comment: I'm glad that was helpful. I'll post in the other question as well.

Answer (score 73):

There is a constructor in `ObservableCollection` that does this:

```
ObservableCollection<T> oc = new ObservableCollection<T>(List<T> list);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can make a extension method that will let you convert any type of `List` into an `ObservableCollection` easily.

```
public static class CollectionUtils
{
    public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> thisCollection)
    {
        if (thisCollection == null) return null;
        var oc = new ObservableCollection<T>();

        foreach (var item in thisCollection)
        {
            oc.Add(item);
        }

        return oc;
    }
}
```

For example:

```
Products p = new Products();
//add your products

var collection = p.ToObservableCollection(); //use the extension method.
```

Comment: just noticed this wasn't actually returning an ObservableCollection. updated

Answer (score 2):

The class Products is a list. In BuildCollection you access this with the Add method. You don't need an auxiliary structure in my opinion.

To convert list to ObservableCollection use

```
this.Select<Product, ObservableCollection>(p  => p)
```

method on collection.